# Oracle 10g invalid batch Command exception for executeBacth of prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Since from a day I am trying to insert huge data (approx 1.2 million rows of 10 columns in each) using batch processing. Below is my code.

```
PreparedStatement destStmt = destConn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

while(somedata){
     for(i=0;i<columnList.size();i++){
     //setting values of aquery
     }
     destStmt.addBatch();               
            if (++count % batchSize == 0) {             
                destStmt.executeBatch();                
        }       
}
destStmt.executeBatch();
```

here

1. somedata is a result set fetched from another server database.
2. columnList is a list columns in which I am going to copy the data.
3. insert query is dependent on columnList. It's generated dynamically and it is fine.

Exception it is throwing mentioned below.

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:571)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:626)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3892)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryDispatcher.executeInsert(QueryDispatcher.java:97)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryModel.executeInsert(QueryModel.java:13)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryViewModel.executeQuery(QueryViewModel.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:111)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doExecute(BinderImpl.java:1745)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doCommand(BinderImpl.java:1506)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$1500(BinderImpl.java:107)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent0(BinderImpl.java:1375)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:1327)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2743)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2714)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2655)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1721)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1506)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1216)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:601)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:483)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:492)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jan 03, 2017 10:45:04 AM org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener onEvent:1329
SEVERE: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:73)
    at org.zkoss.lang.Exceptions.wrap(Exceptions.java:161)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException$Aide.wrap(UiException.java:44)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:118)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doExecute(BinderImpl.java:1745)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doCommand(BinderImpl.java:1506)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$1500(BinderImpl.java:107)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent0(BinderImpl.java:1375)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:1327)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2743)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2714)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2655)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1721)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1506)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1216)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:601)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:483)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:492)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:571)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:626)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3892)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryDispatcher.executeInsert(QueryDispatcher.java:97)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryModel.executeInsert(QueryModel.java:13)
    at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryViewModel.executeQuery(QueryViewModel.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:111)
    ... 38 more

Jan 03, 2017 10:45:04 AM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError:1363
SEVERE: >>org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
[SQL: 17080, null]
>>java.sql.BatchUpdateException: invalid batch command
>>  at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:571)
>>  at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:626)
>>  at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwBatchUpdateException(DBError.java:665)
>>  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3892)
>>  at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryDispatcher.executeInsert(QueryDispatcher.java:97)
>>  at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryModel.executeInsert(QueryModel.java:13)
>>  at in.net.usit.dbu.web.query.QueryViewModel.executeQuery(QueryViewModel.java:86)
>>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:111)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doExecute(BinderImpl.java:1745)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doCommand(BinderImpl.java:1506)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$1500(BinderImpl.java:107)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent0(BinderImpl.java:1375)
>>  at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:1327)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2743)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2714)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2655)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1721)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1506)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1216)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:601)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:483)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:492)
>>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>>  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>>  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>>  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>>  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
>>  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>>  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>>  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>>  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>>  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown)
```

help me through this.

Comment: Batch-file tag is the Windows Command Shell files.

Comment: #Noodles, Thanks for the response. I did not get you. Please can you elaborate this

Comment: Batch-file tag if you read it says it is about command prompt commands in a file that is executed by cmd.exe. The Windows command line shell. Nothing to do with batch updating of databases. It copies and deletes files and starts programs.

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add the SQL statement that is stored in `insertQuery`

Comment: Which line is line 97 in `QueryDispatcher`

Answer (score 0):

This exception can be thrown by the driver if the bind type changes. Be sure that you use the same setter methods to set the bind data across batch lines.